# How to make ajax created input fields put into an array work

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, keyup

Please how do i make this code work for dynamically generated input fields. It works for static input fields but not within the div with id="attributes" that gets dynamically generated input fields. I have done everything possible to get the javascript to work when input fields are generated with ajax call. Here's a fiddle i made for the static fields https://jsfiddle.net/306h20ng/2/ Thanks.

```
 <div id="attributes"> <!--Start of Div Refreshed on Ajax Page Refresh-->
    <div id="mandatory">
        <h5 style="font-weight:600; color:red;"> Mandatory Attributes</h5> 
    </div>
    </div>

     <div id ="mandatory"> //Static input fields
        <input type="text" id="attr1" name="emailAddress" value="">
        <input type="text" id="attr2" name="emailAddress" value="">
        <input type="text" id="attr3" name="emailAddress" value="">
     </div>
        <input type="text" id="detail" name="username" value="">
```

JS

```
var text = $("#mandatory :input").map(function() {
  return this.id;
}).get();

var attr = [];
for (i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
  attr.push('#' + text[i]);
}
var mat = attr.join(", ");


$(mat).keyup(function() {
  update();

  function update() {
    var val = attr.map(function(a) {
      return $(a).val();
    }).join(",")
    $("#detail").val(val);

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `on()` to [**delegate**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) the event listener to `#mandatory` so any new inputs you add within it will also have the same listener

```
$('#mandatory').on('input', ':input',function(){
   var values = $('#mandatory :input').map(function(){
      return this.value
   }).get()
   $("#detail").val(values.join());
});
```

Note that event `"input"` covers keyup, other key events , paste and change also. Adjust if needed.

Also note none of this is reliant on `id` attribute which over-complicates the code

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/mavcb9oa/1)**</kbd>